# How to have a button in form in Angular 7 which doesn't bubble a submit event?

Tags: angular

I have a button in an Angular 7 form which is only supposed to toggle advanced form options. It works for that but it is also getting caught by my form object and NgForm is running the function which is only supposed to run when the submit button is pressed.

I'm using template driven approach. I'll show here my form element and the button that shouldn't be submitting.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">
```

break

```
<button 
  class="btn btn-success"
  (click)="onDisplayOptions()">
  Toggle more options
</button>
```

Is there any way to specify to Angular that this is not a submit button?

Comment: Default `type` for a `button` is `submit` [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type). What happens when you change the `type` to `button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the button type to 'button' as the default type attribute for a button is 'submit'.

```
<button 
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-success"
  (click)="onDisplayOptions()">
  Toggle more options
</button>
```